# Mysql: create view as select *

Tags: mysql

When you create a view with

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT * FROM table1
```

mysql changes this internally to

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM table1
```

If you add a new column **f4** to table1, view1 still has only the first 3 columns. You have to recreate your view. This is annoying, if you have a lot of views.

Is there a way to make mysql to save **SELECT *** in the view declaration so it always selects all the fields no matter if the table has changed?

Answer (score 1):

`MySql` has a right behaviour.

When you create a view as `SELECT * FROM table1`, MySql changes your code with a full list of fields.

When you change your table structure, the view must be changed by user.

If exists this automatic behaviour you can create an issue of performance when you use a view.

Suppose you add 50 fields, and you use your view in a form, you can change the data load from 3 to 53 fields. No good.

So this behaviour is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A **MySql** View does not use for return a complete definition of a table it's basic use to return a part of the tables with a specification or marge data.
**V**iews would not be of much use without it.The principle also applies if you select from a view that selects from the table if the view selects from the table in a subquery and the view is evaluated using the merge algorithm.View processing is not optimized.
You can see this blog to know what is right with a view to MySql.[View Restrictions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, no. This is how MySQL handles views internally.

Pro tip: don't use views. It's a poor man's way of hiding unnecessary complexity behind another complexity. It's way better to simply do plain query, MySQL performs better that way.

Comment: Thanks for all the infos about views. Even I don't agree to abstain from using views generally. Packing the logic of views directly in the queries can add a lot of complexity to them. And "complex" in application development means "error prone" and "hard to maintain". Most times database performance is not the problem...